# Enable BGSAVE for AWS ElastiCache

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

As per the [ElastiCache Manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/RestrictedCommands.html), BGSAVE is restricted to be executed on the redis nodes.

Is there a way to backup the Database on t1.* and t2.* by changing some settings in parameter groups etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in their documentation:

> For Redis (cluster mode disabled) clusters, backup and restore are not supported on cache.t1.micro or cache.t2.* nodes. All other cache node types are supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/backups.html#backups-constraints

Given they've renamed `config`, you're pretty much out of luck.

Possible ways to get your data backed up:

If your cache is publically accessible, you could try syncing your data to a local running Redis via `slaveof <remote-host> <remote-port>`.  Renaming those commands **alone** won't prevent a slave from attaching.

If the above doesn't work and you desperately need your cache backed up, you could leverage `SCAN` to pull your data out and stash it elsewhere.

https://redis.io/commands/scan